# No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'MyApp': (null). Notifications will not be delivered

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, rubymotion

I've set up my application in the Provisioning Portal and enabled it for APS.

I've set up two provisioning profiles for the application, both specific to this App ID.

I'm building my application with my company's distribution certificate and the ad hoc Provisioning Profile.

I've refreshed and re-downloaded the profiles.

I'm still getting this error when I run my app on my device (looking at the device's log)

```
No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'MyApp': (null). Notifications will not be delivered.
```

Can anyone suggest what I might have missed or help me troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This problem was due to my not configuring Rubymotion's Rakefile properly

check out [this thread](https://twitter.com/gavin_morrice/status/237980675049922561) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in witch order did you do steps mentioned above, but critical for APN to work  (at least get a token) in development environment (distributed AdHoc) is that you create new AdHoc distribution provisioning profile AFTER (and make use of it, of course) you did set up APN for your bundle ID for development.

After I did that (ok, and delete old AdHoc profile from XCode followed by restart XCode, just for luck :) ) it worked like a charm.

Hope this will help somebody.

Executed on:
- XCode 4.6, Mac OS X 10.8.2
- iPad 3, iOS 5.1.1

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and I had to **rebuild my project** to get it to work i.e. start a new project and copy your files over. I think someone said this might be an issue of a partially corrupted image included in your project or the project file itself is partially corrupted.